# Using R to make a barplot with a specific width?

Tags: r, width, bar-chart

I would like to use R to make a barplot of ~100,000 numerical entries. The plot will be dense, which is what I want. So far I am using the following code:

```
sample_var <- c(2,5,3,2,3,2,6,10,20,...)  #Filled with 100,000 entries
barplot(sample_var)
```

The resulting plot is just what I want, but it is a square, whereas I want a long rectangle. Is there a way to set the dimensions of the barplot? I would like to specific an aspect ratio of 10:1 for length x height, or a specific pixel setting of 1000px x 10px. I tried using `xlim` in the barplot function statement, but get an "invalid xlim" warning.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `width` and `hight` when outputting to a file:

```
png(filename="figures.png", width=800, height=200, bg="white") 
sample_var <- c(2,5,3,2,3,2,6,10,20)
barplot(sample_var)
dev.off()
```