# Adjust size/width of barplot plots when using mfrow

Tags: r, plot, graph, bar-chart, par

I want to produce two figures using base R, both showing barplots. The first figure should contain two bar plots and the second figure should contain four bar plots.

I used par(mfrow = c(...)) to arrange multiple bar plots in one figure.
I don't have trouble to produce the figures themselves, but when I save the figures bar widths and tick labels are different in size.

To my understanding, when I produce the second figure with four bar plots and chose double the width of the first figure when exporting, bars and labels should be displayed with the same size in the file. However, the labels are much smaller and the bars have a different width in the second figure. Can anyone tell me why?

Here a simple example:

```
png(filename="plot1.png", width=200, height=300, bg="white")
par(mfrow = c(1, 2), mar = c(1, 2, 1, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0))

barplot(height = c(2,3), width = 1, xlim = c(0,2))
barplot(height = c(2,3), width = 1, xlim = c(0,2))
dev.off()

png(filename="plot2.png", width=400, height=300, bg="white")
par(mfrow = c(1, 4), mar = c(1, 2, 1, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0))

barplot(height = c(2,3), width = 1, xlim = c(0,2))
barplot(height = c(2,3), width = 1, xlim = c(0,2))
barplot(height = c(2,3), width = 1, xlim = c(0,2))
barplot(height = c(2,3), width = 1, xlim = c(0,2))
dev.off()
```

*Plot 1:*

[image: Figure 1]

*Plot 2:*

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using R to make a barplot with a specific width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355679/using-r-to-make-a-barplot-with-a-specific-width)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Even when I use the code to export the plots as suggested in this answer, my problems of unequal bar widths and tick labels remains.  I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `par` and `pdf(width, height)` should be equal.

```
png(filename="plot1.png", width=400, height=300, bg="white")
par(mfrow=c(1, 4), mar=c(1, 2, 1, 1), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
replicate(2, barplot(height=c(2,3), width=1, xlim=c(0,2)))
dev.off()

png(filename="plot2.png", width=400, height=300, bg="white")
par(mfrow=c(1, 4), mar=c(1, 2, 1, 1), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
replicate(4, barplot(height=c(2,3), width=1, xlim=c(0,2)))
dev.off()
```

Another solution is to use `layout`.

```
def.par <- par(no.readonly=TRUE) # save par default, for resetting...

# 1 x 2 plot
layout(matrix(c(1:2, 0, 0), nrow=1, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
layout.show(n=2)  # to inspect layout                        # MARK
replicate(2, barplot(height=c(2,3), width=1, xlim=c(0,2)))

# 1 x 4 plot
layout(matrix(c(1:4), nrow=1, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
layout.show(n=4)  # to inspect layout
replicate(4, barplot(height=c(2,3), width=1, xlim=c(0,2)))

# 2 x 4 plot
layout(matrix(c(1:2, 0, 0, 3:6), nrow=2, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
layout.show(n=6)  # to inspect layout
replicate(2, barplot(height=c(2,3), width=1, xlim=c(0,2)))
replicate(4, barplot(height=c(2,3), width=1, xlim=c(0,2)))

par(def.par)  # reset to default
```

However, both solutions bring a half empty plot 1, the reason can be seen in code above at `# MARK`.

We could use the `magick` package to "chop" the first plot to the desired content. First we create the `*.png`s with the second method.

```
clr <- "#ED7C22"  # color

png(filename="plot1.png", width=400, height=300, bg="white")
layout(matrix(c(1:2, 0, 0), nrow=1, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
replicate(2, barplot(height=c(2,3), width=1, xlim=c(0,2), col=clr, border=0))
dev.off()

png(filename="plot2.png", width=400, height=300, bg="white")
layout(matrix(c(1:4), nrow=1, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
replicate(4, barplot(height=c(2,3), width=1, xlim=c(0,2), col=clr, border=0))
dev.off()
```

Now, using `image_chop` we trim `plot1.png` to it's left half.

```
library(magick)
(i <- image_read("plot1.png"))
i.chopped <- image_chop(i, "200x+200")  # says: trim by 200px at pos. 200
```

Finally, we export the chopped image.

```
image_write(i.chopped, path="plot1.ch.png", format="png")
```

#### Plot 1 ("chopped")

[image]

#### Plot 2

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but then I get the right half of the first plot as white space. That's unfavourable when I want the graph on just half a page in my document.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's ugly. There's a solution applying `magick::image_chop`, see update.

Comment: That's a good workaround for this problem. Thank you. But I still don't understand why R changes the proportions in the graphs when I use four instead of two plots with double the image width. Is there no explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: @VincentH. The plots are automatically adjusted internally so that no free space is created. Thereupon this solution was generalized, probably because this occurs more often than you need different sized sets of plots with the same aspect ratio each. However, I missed an `aspect` option in `barplot`. Since `plot` has this option it might be worthwhile to check if `plot` produces equal aspects setting this option.